# PHP(Codeigniter) building array tree assign key name respectively to Grand child of array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

After too many search on different forums i decided to ask for help . I am building data array for

America ->
            
         TV Channels ->
                                    
                      Dramas ->
                                                            
                                Episodes

As you can see there are Four levels . I am using this code to develop it

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

public function index() {
    $arr = array(
        array(
            'id' => 100,
            'dramaID' => 0,
            'Country name' => 'America'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 101,
            'dramaID' => 100,
            'Channels' => 'Tv Channels',
            'url' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 102,
            'dramaID' => 101,
            'Dramaname' => 'Taken',
            'url' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 103,
            'dramaID' => 102,
            'Episodename' => 'Episode 1',
            'url' => ''
        )
    );
```

// items which match their `id` to `dramaID` are nested in a `children` array

```
    $results = $this->array_tree($arr, 'id', 'dramaID', 'channels');
    echo"<pre>";
    print_r($results);
}

function array_tree($arr, $main_index, $parent_index, $child_index) {

    $new = array();
    foreach ($arr as $a) {
        $new[$a[$parent_index]][] = $a;
    }

    // we create a closure in order to be recursive
    function create_tree(&$list, $parent, $i, $c) {
        $tree = array();
        foreach ($parent as $k => $l) {
            if (isset($list[$l[$i]])) {
                $l[$c] = create_tree($list, $list[$l[$i]], $i, $c);
            }
            $tree[] = $l;
        }
        return $tree;
    }

    return create_tree($new, $new[0], $main_index, $child_index);
}
```

}
and its giving this OUTPUT 
[image]

OUTPUT needed [image]

Please help . What change i need to do in code so i can pass the key names ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include "type" in your array and then use conditions as follows

```
<?php
 $arr = array(
    array(
        'id' => 100,
        'parentid' => 0,
        'type' => 'country',
        'Country name' => 'America'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 101,
        'parentid' => 100,
        'Channels' => 'Tv Channels',
        'type' => 'channel',
        'url' => ''
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 102,
        'parentid' => 101,
        'Dramaname' => 'Taken',
        'type' => 'drama',
        'url' => ''
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 103,
        'parentid' => 102,
        'Episodename' => 'Episode 1',
        'type' => 'episode',
        'url' => ''
    ),
         array(
        'id' => 104,
        'parentid' => 103,
        'Episodename' => 'Episode 2',
        'type' => 'episode',
        'url' => ''
    ),
  array(
        'id' => 105,
        'parentid' => 103,
        'Episodename' => 'Episode 2',
        'type' => 'episode',
        'url' => ''
    ),
 array(
        'id' => 106,
        'parentid' => 103,
        'Episodename' => 'Episode 4',
        'type' => 'episode',
        'url' => ''
    )
);


 $results = array_tree($arr, 'id', 'parentid', 'channels');
echo"<pre>";
  print_r($results);


function array_tree($arr, $main_index, $parent_index, $child_index) {

$new = array();
foreach ($arr as $a) {
    $new[$a[$parent_index]][] = $a;
}

// we create a closure in order to be recursive
function create_tree(&$list, $parent, $i, $c) {
    $tree = array();
    foreach ($parent as $k => $l) {
           if (isset($list[$l[$i]])) {
               foreach ($list[$l[$i]] as $nouman=>$abc){
                    if($abc['type']=='country'){
                        $l['country'] = create_tree($list, $list[$l[$i]], $i, 'country');
                   }

                   if($abc['type']=='channel'){
                        $l['channel'] = create_tree($list, $list[$l[$i]], $i, 'channel');
                   }

                      if($abc['type']=='drama'){
                        $l['drama'] = create_tree($list, $list[$l[$i]], $i, 'drama');
                   }

                    if($abc['type']=='episode'){
                        $l['episode'] = create_tree($list, $list[$l[$i]], $i, 'episode');
                   }

               }

          }
        $tree[] = $l;
    }
    return $tree;
}

return create_tree($new, $new[0], $main_index, $child_index);

}

?>
```

Comment: Boom ! works like a charm ! :) thank you so much for help

Answer (score 0):

If you want a hierarchical array structure. You can create the array like this

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'id' => 100,
        'dramaID' => 0,
        'Country name' => 'America'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 101,
        'dramaID' => 100,
        'Channels' => 'Tv Channels',
        'url' => ''
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 102,
        'dramaID' => 101,
        'Dramaname' => 'Taken',
        'url' => ''
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 103,
        'dramaID' => 102,
        'Episodename' => 'Episode 1',
        'url' => ''
    )
);
```

Comment: Yes , using the same structure . Do you have idea how to change the key names of child arrays using this code ?